# Angular Observables: How to optimize subscription / subscribe vs async

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I have the following component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'summary-dialog',
    templateUrl: './summary-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./summary-dialog.component.css']
})
export class SummaryDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    entriesSummaries: GuiEntrySummary[];
    private interval;

    constructor(private backendService: BackendService,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SummaryDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: {
            eventDbid: number,
            timerState: TimerState,
            entries: IGuiEntry[]
        }) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.entriesSummaries = this.data.entries.map(entry => new GuiEntrySummary(entry));
        this.getSummaries();

        // automatic refresh the entries summaries every 10 secs
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.getSummaries();
        }, 10000)

        this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => clearInterval(this.interval));
    }

    private getSummaries(): void {
        this.backendService.getSummaries(this.data.eventDbid, this.data.timerState.elapsedSeconds).subscribe(entriesSummaries =>
            entriesSummaries.forEach(entrySummaries =>
                this.entriesSummaries.find(entry => entry.dbid === entriesSummaries.dbid).summaries = entrySummaries.summaries
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This component is a dialog. Every entry ( data -> entries ) is an own row in the dialog. The already resolved entries will be passed into the dialog, which are the base for the displayed data. Every entry will be enriched with an summary array.
The component should refresh the summaries of all entries every 10 seconds.

But my main problem here is the understanding how to implement this usecase in an acceptable way.

Is it really bad to subscribe in the component in this case? Primarly I do that, because the template should display the existing data all the time, even in the short period when the new data will be fetched from the backendService.

If I would do this in the async way (e.g.:

```html
<div *ngIf="( getAllEntriesSummaries |async ) as entriesSummaries">
```

), I would image, that the container won't be displayed in the exact moment of fetching the new data. Furthermore I would need another function call in the template, which will merge the data of the current data with the new one?!

With my current solution (with the maybe anti pattern of subscribe in the component) I have a very clean template:

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Entries Summaries</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">

    <div class="grid">

        <div *ngFor="let entry of entriesSummaries; let i = index" class="entry-row"
            [ngClass]="i % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-even' : 'bg-odd'">

            <!--entry row -->

        </div>
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timer` RxJS operator like so:

```js
entriesSummaries$: Observable<GuiEntrySummary[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.entriesSummaries$ = timer(0, 10000).pipe(exhaustMap(() => this.getSummaries()));
}

private getSummaries(): Observable<GuiEntrySummary[]> {
   return this.backendService.getSummaries(this.data.eventDbid, this.data.timerState.elapsedSeconds).pipe(tap(() => /* side effects */));
  }
```

```html
 <div *ngIf="(getAllEntriesSummaries$ | async) as entriesSummaries">
```

> From the docs:
> `timer` returns an Observable that emits an infinite sequence of ascending integers, with a constant interval of time, period of your choosing between those emissions. The first emission happens after the specified dueTime. The initial delay may be a Date. By default, this operator uses the {@link asyncScheduler} {@link SchedulerLike} to provide a notion of time, but you may pass any {@link SchedulerLike} to it. If period is not specified, the output Observable emits only one value, 0. Otherwise, it emits an infinite sequence.

I won't say that subscribing in the component is a bad practice, however, it is recommended to use the `async` pipe for better performance especially if your using OnPush change detection.

Comment: Ok, but now the part of connecting the entries with the received summaries are missing (the filter part in my question). Where exactly I should do that? The backend service fetches only the summaries, which have than be connected with the entriesSummaries. Should I do that during the backendService call with map?

Comment: Yes, you can use `map` operator if you want to transform your data, or you can use the `filter` operator if you want to filter the data based on a condition or both. It depends on your use case. If you don't want to change the data and you only want to add some side effects you can use the `tap` operator which is similar to `forEach` method, but keep in mind that `tap` as `forEach` doesn't return anything. Looking at your code, I'm not sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Basically I only want to enrich the existing data with the summaries. So I would image that map should be the correct operator for that

Comment: It might be.  I'm still confused about the functionality you want to implement. Instead of `timer` you might need to use `interval` and `startWith` operators. The argument that you pass to `startWith` is `this.data.entries.map(entry => new GuiEntrySummary(entry))`. If you need further help, provide a StackBlitz and I'll have a look. Cheers!